# Discord bot sending multiple messages at once even though set Interval value is 60000(1 minute)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready!")
})

client.on('message', message =>{
    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
   
    const generalBotTesting = '598918505605234723';
    function cheekibreeki(){
        client.channels.cache.get(generalBotTesting).send("Cheeki Breeki")    
    }
    setInterval(cheekibreeki,60000)
}
)

client.login(process.env.token);
```

My bot is spamming multiple messages even though set Interval value is for to send the message only once every minute

Comment: Not familiar with their API but it seems like you are listening to a message and then you just send it, it's a loop because everytime there is a new message you send one. But you also send a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting a new interval on every message *received*, what you want to do is start one single interval when the client is connected to the Discord API.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready!")
    
    setInterval(cheekibreeki, 60 * 1000)
})

const generalBotTesting = '598918505605234723';
    
function cheekibreeki(){
    client.channels.cache.get(generalBotTesting).send("Cheeki Breeki")    
}



client.on('message', message =>{
    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
})



client.login(process.env.token);
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution fixed my problem and saved my sanity